# How do I change the map-change time after the game ends on my server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For my CS:GO offensive server, how do I change the amount of time it takes to change map once a game ends on my server?  Currently it is set to 1 min and 30 sec, when 10 seconds would suffice.

Answer (score 6):

Taken from here: [CSGO](http://www.gamerconfig.eu/commands/counter-strike-global-offensive/)

> > **mp_timelimit 0**
>
> Game time per map in minutes.

This should be the command used to modify the time to change the map time. Since there are no commands to directly modify the time it takes to change maps, I suggest you use the next following command:

> > **mp_roundtime "5"**
>
> How many minutes each round takes.

Since you want a 10 second mapchange time, mp_timelimit should be 29, while mp_roundtime should be 4. (Thus, 7 rounds of 4 minutes each, and with additional time from other events, such as half-time, warm-up, etc.)

Here are a list of other commands associated with "time-related" issues:

```
mp_halftime_duration "15" // Number of seconds that halftime lasts
mp_round_restart_delay "7" // Number of seconds to delay before restarting a round after a win
mp_restartgame "0" // game will restart in the specified number of seconds
```

Honestly though, what it boils down to is really you can't really change it.  There are so many things to factor in (If you're playing DE modes, then if the bomb is planted before the round ends, you'll have to factor that time in too).  There are a lot of things to factor in when determining how long each map within the rotation is run as well as determining how long your rounds are.